# Stream data from variable to PUT request

Tags: node.js, stream

What I've been looking to do is make a `GET` request and then manipulate the JSON data store that in a variable and then make a `PUT` request. Can't seem to find documentation on this. Maybe I am thinking about this wrong. Once I have the variable I want to do something like the below. I have all of my data from the `GET` request saved to an `outputV3.json` file.

```
var outputJson = fs.readFileSync("outputV3.JSON");
outputJson = JSON.parse(outputJson);

(function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < outputJson.objects.length; i++) {
    let postId = outputJson.objects[i].id.toString();
    let newSlug = outputJson.objects[i].slug.replace("blog/", "");
    let urlToPut = "https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?limit=1000&hapikey=" + process.env.HAPIKEY;

    urlToPut = urlToPut.replace("blogPostId", postId);

    let put_data = JSON.stringify({
      "slug": newSlug
    });

    put_data.put(urlToPut);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @James Zich. if this or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, however, I've noticed throughout your posts history that you are not marking any answers at all, which is not the way SO operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stream your data from file to request, you should create [read stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) from the file and [pipe](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) it to the destination:

```
const dataStream = fs.createReadStream('outputV3.JSON');

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/destination',
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  // response processing...
});

dataStream.pipe(req);
```

And if you need more advanced logic for streaming you should consider putting a custom [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) stream between readable file stream and writable request stream.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to use request-promise could I do something like the following

```
let options = {
uri: 'https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?limit=1000&hapikey=' + process.env.HAPIKEY,
method: 'GET'
transform: function (body, response) {
    return for(var i=0; i<outputJson.objects.length; i++) {
    var postId = outputJson.objects[i].id.toString();
    var newSlug = outputJson.objects[i].slug.replace("blog/","");
}
};

rp(options)
.then(function(removedSlug) {
.pipe(request.put('https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-
posts/blogPostId?hapikey=' + process.env.HAPIKEY))
});
```